# Excel DATEVALUE function

Tags: excel

I am implementing a helper function similar to Excel's `datevalue` function in another programing language.

Is there any special name used for the way excel serializes the value? otherwise will name it as `toExcelDate`.

Sorry, it might sound silly but I tried searching and couldn't find any name as such.

Comment: `DateValue` takes a string and outputs a date in the user's locale, I think. You may look to implement overloads that allow you to specify the format that needs to be parsed, and/or the format of the output, e.g., because a rather notorious problem when dealing with dates is whether "04-06-2018" is June 4 or April 6, etc.

Comment: On a related note, you should probably tag this with the language you're using. It's possible such a function already exists, and if so, it's silly to waste your time reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: Microsoft Office documentation states that the result is the serial number of the date. Perhaps 'toDateSerialNumber' or similar? - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252

Comment: I am actually looking for a name for excel way of serializing the date rather than calling it 'toExcelDate' (e.g. toGeorgianDate, toJulianDate)

Comment: For example in US locale, `DateValue("09-05-2018")` returns 9/5/2018 (Sep. 5), but `DateValue("31-05-2018")` returns 5/31/2018 (May 31).